# Null pointer request when trying to test with Hibernate and Mockito

Tags: java, hibernate, testing, mockito

I'm trying to make a test for this method inside UserHibernateDao:

```
@Transactional
public User create(final String firstName, final String lastName, final String email,
                    final String password, final String phoneNumber, String role) {


    final User user = new User(firstName, lastName, email, password, phoneNumber, role, request.getHeader("Accept-Language").substring(0, MAX_LANGUAJE));

    em.persist(user);
    return user;
}
```

In order to test this method I need to autowire the variables in my test but I get a null pointer exception in request and entity manager as if the variables where never initialized.

TestConfig.java

```
@ComponentScan({"src.main.java.ar.edu.itba.paw.persistence"})
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TestConfig {

     @Mock
     @Autowired
     private UserHibernateDao userHibernateDao;

     @Bean
     @Autowired
     public UserHibernateDao getUserHibernateDao() {
         return userHibernateDao;
     }

     @Bean
     public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactory() {
         final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
         factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("ar.edu.itba.paw.models");
         factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
         final JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
         factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
         final Properties properties = new Properties();
         properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
         properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
         properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
         properties.setProperty("format_sql", "true");
         factoryBean.setJpaProperties(properties);
         return factoryBean;
       }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final SimpleDriverDataSource ds = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClass(JDBCDriver.class);
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:paw");
        ds.setUsername("ha");
        ds.setPassword("");
        return ds;
    }

     @Bean
     public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
          return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
     }
}
```

UserJDBCDaoTest (ignore the JDBC name):

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
@Sql("classpath:userScript.sql")
@Transactional
public class UserJdbcDaoTest {

    private static final long USERID = 1;
    private static final long NONEXISTENTUSERID = -1;
    private static final String FIRSTNAME = "TestFirstName";
    private static final String NEWFIRSTNAME = "TestNewFirstName";
    private static final String LASTNAME = "TestLastName";
    private static final String EMAIL = "test1@mail.com";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "TestPassword";
    private static final String PHONENUMBER = "1522334455";
    private static final String ROLE = "role";

    private User user;  

    @Autowired
    private UserHibernateDao userHibernateDao;  

    @Autowired
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.userHibernateDao = new UserHibernateDao();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateUser() {
        //JdbcTestUtils.deleteFromTables(jdbcTemplate, "users");

        user = Mockito.mock(User.class);
        when(user.getFirstName()).thenReturn(FIRSTNAME);
        when(user.getLastName()).thenReturn(LASTNAME);
        when(user.getEmail()).thenReturn(EMAIL);
        when(user.getPassword()).thenReturn(PASSWORD);
        when(user.getPhoneNumber()).thenReturn(PHONENUMBER);
        when(user.getRole()).thenReturn(ROLE);

        User u = userHibernateDao.create(FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL, PASSWORD, PHONENUMBER, ROLE);

        Assert.assertNotNull(u);
        Assert.assertEquals(u.getFirstName(), user.getFirstName());
        Assert.assertEquals(u.getLastName(), user.getLastName());
        Assert.assertEquals(EMAIL, user.getEmail());
        Assert.assertEquals(PASSWORD, user.getPassword());
        Assert.assertEquals(PHONENUMBER, user.getPhoneNumber());
        Assert.assertEquals(ROLE, user.getRole());
        //Assert.assertEquals(1, JdbcTestUtils.countRowsInTable(jdbcTemplate, "users"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is the null pointer exception on?

Comment: @DavidLavender at the line where it says:  `final User user = new User(firstName, lastName, email, password, phoneNumber, role, request.getHeader("Accept-Language").substring(0, MAX_LANGUAJE))`

Comment: @DavidLavender since the request is null, it ends up throwing an exception.